# How to limit steepness of inv exp curve?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I am trying to implement a motorised system that will move an object whose velocity has the shape of an inverse exponential curve. In other words it will begin very fast and then slowly come to a halt.

I have a problem in that the initial steepness of the curve is too high meaning that the acceleration of the motor is more than it can handle. I want a gentler slope ***whilst still moving the same distance within the same time limit***.

So I have

$$y = a(1-r)^t$$

I have rearranged this as:

$$t = \frac{\ln(y/a)}{\ln(1-r)}$$

The motor that I am using is a stepper motor which is triggered by pulses. Each pulse moves the motor one more step (with e.g. 200 steps / revolution). The faster I send pulses, the faster it moves. I therefore need to calculate how much time to wait before sending the next pulse so that the motor's velocity follows an exponential curve; starting quickly and eventually coming to a halt.

In the above equation,
$y$ is the number of steps left (i.e. the height of the curve),
$a$ is the total number of steps + 1,
and $r$ is the rate of decay.

So if I want to move 955 steps within 3 seconds,

$$r = 1 - (1/956)^{1/3}$$

So how can I modify the equation, $t = \ln(y/a) / \ln(1-r)$ so as to soften the steepness of this curve and still stay within the boundaries of 955 steps and 3s?

Since I know what the maximum torque of the motor is, I know what the maximum acceleration it can handle is. Ideally, I'd therefore like to have an equation whose maximum steepness (ie $dy/dt$) would not exceed a given limit.

Perhaps this picture will help explain what I'm trying to do:

[image: crude drawing of less steep curve]

Comment: What about the velocity decaying exponentially $v(t) = v_0 e^{-kt}$, with $v_0$ being the initial (maximum) velocity and $k$ being some reasonable value for your motor (if $k$ is small the decay is longer).

Comment: Thanks @Ertxiem but I'm not sure that that solves the issue of boundaries. How would that work when I have to decay from say, 955 to zero in 3 seconds? If I reduce k then I don't get close to zero until 5 seconds, 10, or longer. I must keep within 3 s.

Comment: What if $k=3$? If that is not good enough, try to select a higher value of the constant $k$.

Comment: I haven't thought this through but here's an idea that might help. If you scale the $x$ axis by a varying amount $x^s$ for a fixed $s < 1$ you change the rate at which $x$ grows from $0$ to $1$., You can adjust $s$ and make it work more or less steeply on the interval between $0$ and $3$.

Comment: The following has been proposed as a solution:

y = be^(x-d)/a - c

b adjusts the height of the curve to match the distance to travel that I require (starting point of y).

a adjusts the steepness of the curve

c shifts the curve down so that we reach y=0 at the right time, t.

d is used to shift the graph to the left.

However, I'm not sure now that I could achieve an inverse exp curve in real life. The initial velocity - and hence acceleration - would be too great. I think that I need a sigmoid curve that is skewed to the left so as to approximate an exponential decay.